# Connect to SOAP using Java NetBeans

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, jax-ws, soapui

I can successfully connect to a SOAP service using SOAP UI.
However, I cannot find a good guide on connecting to the SOAP service using Java NetBeans where I need to pass username+password to SOAP, can someone suggest a good tutorial/guide for this purpose?

My example below that works with SOAP UI, but doesn't work correctly when I try to use Java like JAX WS...

See the SOAP UI screenshot here from dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3iwrees1ph36j0k/soap.png?dl=0 
or Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qlCIai7vD3X05LMVA2YUo1ejQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can't see your attachments if there is no dropbox login.

Comment: You want to write a java program to send SOAP request and get SOAP response. Am I correct?

Comment: @pasupathi  correct, the SOAP has username and password, but I cannot find the code to enter username and password in JAX WS

Comment: @Rao I updated the link, you should be able to see now

Comment: @kengcc you can use either HTTPUrlConnection http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/ 
Or you can use Apache HTTP client http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/